# Recover just deleted scanned pdf without unmounting

Tags: data-recovery, pdf

I have just deleted a scanned pdf file.

I'm trying to recover it with `scalpel`.

The problem is that scalpel will recover many deleted files and
names them numerically (e.g. 0001.pdf, 0002.pdf, ... 9999.pdf).

According to [this tutorial](http://www.pronique.com/blog/howto-recover-deleted-php-files-using-scalpel) I could use a `grep` command and search
some text in the deleted file.

The problem is, that the file is scanned (I know the original file name),
so I don't know what to search for.

Comment: It might not be so easy to grep text even if you did know what to look for, since there is some compression and other binary junk mixed in with text, if any. Did you enable OCR when scanning? Also do you know if scalpel names them numerically in the order of last modified or is it some arbitrary order?

Comment: @user454038 It is scanned without OCR. I don't know if scalpel do some ordering.

Comment: You need to make backups. In addition, put your scans under version control. That's what I do. With distributed version control, you can easily push your repository to a remote location, so that's a form of backup, though not a substitute for proper backups.

Answer (score 5):

If you can scan the document again, you might be able to automatically compare that against the recovered documents. But if that is the case you probably don't need to recover.

That leaves finding the right PDF, and since opening them one by one in programs like `evince` is cumbersome I recommend you run the following in the directory where the `.pdf` files are recovered:

```
for i in *.pdf ; do
  pdfimages -j -l 1 "$i" "${i%}"
done
```

This will leave with JPEG files (`-j` option, unless the scanned file was not JPEG, which is unlikely) with the first page ( `-l 1` ) with same basename as your PDFs.

Now you can use `eog` to quickly browse through the extracted images until you (visually) recognise the document you are looking for. Once found the image file will have the same basename as the PDF file you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Try running `pdfinfo` on your files.

The output may have `Creator: Simple Scan` or similar in it, so you can search for that.

You can also try using the `CreationDate` field if you know the approximate date of creation.

Of course `pdfinfo` will return an error if the file isn't a PDF file, so you'll need to send errors to `/dev/null`.

Try scanning a document using Simple Scan, and see what output `pdfinfo` returns for it.

Comment: Actually, pdfinfo found about 50 files, so I had to open it manually. But the one file I was looking for wasn't between them. I'm not sure if I can trust this tool (scalpel). Maybe this answer is worth accepting, but I would like to recover the file in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The scan image data in the PDF file will most likely be preceded by something like

```
<</BitsPerComponent 1/ColorSpace/DeviceGray/DecodeParms<</Columns 2480/K -1>>/Filter/CCITTFaxDecode/Height 3507/Length 96349/Name/Im0/Subtype/Image/Type/XObject/Width 2480>>stream
```

I'd therefore start to narrow things down with `grep -Fil 'subtype/image' filenames`. This will at least rule out PDF files which do not contain an image.

Comment: This finds hundreds of scanned files. My pdf file is output of simple-scan application, so I guess according to the size of similar scanned documents, that the resulting file should be (6 pages) 354K +/- in size. If it would be possible to add some switch to the grep command that will narrow the results yet.

Comment: btw. your command does not narrow the results to scanned documents.

Comment: I know the creation date of the original file yet, if it helps.